# What is HZSM-5?

Tags: catalysis

What is HZSM-5? I have seen it used as a catalyst support in literature. It seems to be related to the ZSM-5 zeolite, but I am not sure how.

Comment: see http://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=34583.0 $\ce{H^+}$ instead of $\ce{Na^+}$ at ion exchange site.

Comment: It can also be used as an acid catalyst in its own right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this article(1), the difference between the zeolites HZSM-5 and ZSM-5 is that the first has a monoclinic and the second has an orthorhombic framework.

(1) H. van Koningsveld, J.C. Jansen, H. van Bekkum, *The monoclinic framework structure of zeolite H-ZSM-5. Comparison with the orthorhombic framework of as-synthesized ZSM-5, Zeolites*, Volume 10, Issue 4, **1990**, Pages 235-242